# How can I improve performance with a big table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent container which holds a table(each row is a child component).
The child component is a bit heavy in terms of data(has many images)

So it looks like:

```
<parent>
    <child> </child>
    <child> </child>
    <child> </child>
    ...
</parent>
```

Not when I re-render the parent component(child component is stopped at shouldComponentUpdate, so doesnt re-render), it takes a lot of time.

Perf.timeWasted not showing anything.

When i re-render a single child it re-renders fast.

Maybe it regards the react virtual DOM calculations?

Is there any other tests/directions i should look at?

**EDIT**:

The child's shouldComponentUpdate is very small, looks like:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let shouldUpdate =nextProps.test1;
    return shouldUpdate;
}
```

Comment: @leo the code is very big, I posted the structure, I can paste specific code parts

Comment: post how you render a child in the parent?

Comment: @leo done, its a very simple, not heavy shouldComponentUpdate, no problems there

Comment: is test1 boolean? If not, then you should do return !!shouldUpdate. Anyways, from the info given can't help you much ;-(

Comment: <parent><child>...</parent> is not a Table. That's plain HTML unles it is <table> <tr><td>... etc and we cant help you if its not

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use InfiniteLoader from liblary [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) or [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite). Thanks this libraries will be rendered only visible components. This increase your performance.